# Not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs... cant go from USB either

Tags: boot, usb, kernel, mount

After reviewing the other "Kernel panic..." I'm on my own.  There seem to be a few ways to recover, IF (and only if) one can use an alternate method to boot.  I've seen some other methods that mention the boot from USB then mount ...  However, I mount the previous /dev/sda1 but don't get everything needed to mount the old system and chroot, so I'm left with trying to "upgrade from USB..."  Long story short(ened), After most of today, I've not gotten anywhere with it.

Other net-provided solutions mention update-initrdramfs.  That will not run on a system loaded from USB, for obvious reasons, and I cannot seem to be able to get to that point.

Is there a way to just cp the initrd-... to the right place??  Actually, before that, is there another way to get enough of the old system mounted so that I can just replace the initrd file??  Or, alternately, is there a method to upgrade from the USB stick?  After SEVERAL attempts, I'm a bit frustrated...

Comment: didn't you have grub installed so could boot another kernel?   I had a system fail (caps) so drive was swapped to another same-model box but kernel panic (turned out motherboard was different).  In that case I did `cp` in a kernel that booted on that mboard, and cp'd in full kernel (not just the initrd or initial-ramdisk) and box was back up.

Comment: I've booted every version in my "GRUBS" list.  All previous versions at least get past the initrd, but fail when trying to establish connection to the gpu.  I"ve booted current version from USB and next version from USB, but neither with allow mount of subsequent systems to allow for chroot.  (as mentioned above).  I lose like the last month and a half's work if I lose this partition or I would simply rebuilt from scratch.

Comment: if you boot to maintenance/recovery/single user mode what do you get?  (asking this because of gpu mention).  ie. <e> or edit a kernel that gets past initrd, remove `quiet spash` and add a `1` (or single).  If you've added a password to grub, you'll have to enter it when requested.

Comment: Turns out that I couldn't get around the Kernel Panic per se.  However, I eventually, made a bootable USB drive, then listed the available disks ("sudo fdisk -l") I mounted the original drive and was fortunate to find at least my code from the past few months - so at least I didn't lose all of that work.

I, of course couldn't make things easy as it was encrypted, so I had to go through the whole "Crypto_LUKS" thing.  Then to figure out drive name etc... "sudo lvmdiskscan" followed by "sudo pvs" and using the info garnered thereby, I was able to get through it.

Answer (score 0):

if you boot to maintenance/recovery/single user mode what do you get? (asking this because of gpu mention). ie.  or edit a kernel that gets past initrd, remove quiet spash and add a 1 (or single). If you've added a password to grub, you'll have to enter it when requested. – guiverc Jan 17 at 1:23

Turns out that I couldn't get around the Kernel Panic per se. However, I eventually, made a bootable USB drive, then listed the available disks ("sudo fdisk -l") I mounted the original drive and was fortunate to find at least my code from the past few months - so at least I didn't lose all of that work. I, of course couldn't make things easy as it was encrypted, so I had to go through the whole "Crypto_LUKS" thing. Then to figure out drive name etc... "sudo lvmdiskscan" followed by "sudo pvs" and using the info garnered thereby, I was able to get through it.